# How do I use Moq to validate Enterprise Library Logging?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, logging, moq, enterprise-library

I want to create a unit test that validates a Logger.Write command is executed with the correct message in one of my MVC controllers.

I can mock the Listener that the Logger writes to, but I do not know how to reach the message that is stored. For example,

```
var mockListener = new Mock<MyTraceListener>();
// the .Write method is void so I can't use .Returns() on my mock
mockListener.Setup(listener => listener.Write(It.IsAny<string>()))

MyController controller = new MyController();
MyController.Index();
```

// and then the Index method calls the following Logger.Write() to the category that writes to MyTraceListener:

```
Logger.Write("test message", "MyCategory");
```

This write command to the logger does not return the input string or store it into a parameter for me to validate with an Assertion statement. Can I use one of the Moq verifies or setups or the .when (whatever this is) functions to get the message that is logged, or at least check that it executed?

Preferably, I want to store the log entry into a variable in my unit test so I can assert this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(loggedMessage, "test message");
```

If anyone knows of a strategy to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Entlib 5.0, there's already a mock point for you. Instead of using Logger.Write directly, instead inject an instance of LogWriter into your controller. You can then mock out the LogWriter object in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Callback as a way to get the input from your Write method back to your unit test.

Because Loggers is static, you'll have to wrap the calls to those static methods in order to use Moq in your tests. The sample class below should be all you need to do to pull that off. You'll also have to update your code to use the wrapper, that might be painful.

Here is a sample test and class structure to achieve this.

```
public class Logger
{ 
   public virtual void Write( string message, string category )
   {
      Loggers.Write( message, category );
   }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SampleTest()
{
   string input = string.Empty;

   var mockLogger = new Mock<Logger>();
   mockLogger.Setup( l => l.Write( It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>() ) ).Callback( ( string message, string category ) => input = message );


   mockLogger.Object.Write( "test", "category" );

   Assert.AreEqual( "test", input );
}
```

Please note I'm using Moq version 4.0.10827.0.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is helpful. Can I configure this to detect the Logger.Write commands in my controller source code, instead of the mockLogger in the test method?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking correctly, you would need to setup the mock logger and inject that into your controller as a dependency in order to get it hooked up the way you want.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to avoid. I am fairly inexperienced, and that doesn't seem like a good coding practice to me.

Comment: Dependency injection is a powerful tool to use. It can also allow you to write tests that end up testing multiple layers at once. For your situation it seems like you are doing just that. If you could have tests to verify the logging behavior, you don't need to test the logging functionality at the controller layer.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I can have one test to validate logging functionality, and another test to validate my controller actually executed some logging write (without regards to whether or not it logged correctly). 
What's the best way to assert that a logger write was accessed? Perhaps using a mock logger and its Verify function? EDIT: I can't mock Loggers because they are static classes.

Comment: You will have to use the Adapter Pattern in order to test the Loggers functionality. I'll update my answer to reflect that.